# Scaling form elements in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to scale up form elements of a form with a Bootstrap 4 so they would stretch to the whole row width?

The arrangement I have now looks horrible: http://prntscr.com/id6pfm

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <form class="form-group" method='POST' action='reset_password.php' enctype=utf-8 accept-charset=utf-8>
                        <input class="form-block" type='password' name='password' placeholder="New password" size='20'>
                        <input class="form-block" type='password' name='password_confirm' placeholder="Confirm new password" size='20'>
                        <input class="form-block" type='submit' value='Reset password'></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the following meta tag in the head of the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

And make sure you remove the unnecessary custom css. Bootstrap 4 is flexbox-based by default.

Here's a starter template you can use for all your documents:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm totally clueless about front-end dev, so I'd never have guessed about viewport! Thanks!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the `col-xs-*` class group doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4 anymore. It has been replaced with just `col-*`.

Comment: And check out the most recent docs for form groups here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-groups